# Want to enter data with duplicate entries in mysql

Tags: mysql

Im new to MySQL, Can you please help me with these entries. I want to enter the table below but i am getting following error

```
*ERROR 1062: 1062: Duplicate entry '2014-03-14' for key 'PRIMARY'*

SQL Statement:

INSERT INTO `database`.`table1` (`Date`, `ID Number`, `Type`, `Time1`, `Time2`,       `Time3`, `Time4`, `Time5`) VALUES ('2014-03-14', 'UCN1121A', 'Others', '1', '7', '45', '3',   '17')



Date           ID Number Type  Time1  Time2   Time3   Time4    Time5   
3/14/2014   ID1 Type1   2   4   5   10  12
3/14/2014   ID1 Type2   1   7   45  3   17
3/14/2014   ID1 Type3   0   0   1   0   2
3/14/2014   ID1 Type4   1   0   0   0   0
3/14/2014   ID1 Type5   0   3   5   0   0
3/14/2014   ID1 Type6   0   0   0   0   0
3/14/2014   ID1 Type1   3   1   3   5   1
3/14/2014   ID2 Type2   3   0   0   2   1
3/14/2014   ID3 Type3   12  4   5   7   8
3/14/2014   ID4 Type4   0   0   0   0   0
3/14/2014   ID5 Type5   0   0   0   8   0
3/14/2014   ID6 Type6   0   0   0   0   0
3/14/2014   ID3 Type1   0   1   4   1   0
3/14/2014   ID4 Type2   12  15  69  34  15
3/14/2014   ID5 Type3   0   0   0   0   0
3/14/2014   ID6 Type4   13  2   46  8   9
3/14/2014   ID7 Type5   0   0   0   0   0
3/14/2014   ID8 Type6   0   0   0   0   0
```

Comment: what's the primary key of the table?

Comment: `ALTER TABLE database.table1 DROP PRIMARY KEY`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Date` column in your `table1` table is the primary key. This means each row in the table must have a unique value for this column. If you try to insert a row with a value for the primary key column that already exists in the table, the database engine will not allow it. That's what the error message means. Either change the value of the `Date` column in your insert statement to something unique, or remove the primary key designation from that column.

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked perfectly.I am Still learning the tricks :)